# Applying for Turkey visa

Tags: visas, turkey, egyptian-citizens

I am Egyptian. I live in Saudi Arabia and have a valid Schengen visa. Do I need to apply for a visa for Turkey or can I get it at the airport?

Comment: How are you planning to travel to Turkey?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo comment removed

Answer (score 1):

According to Turkey's page on [Visa Information For Foreigners](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa):

> **Egypt**: Official passport holders are exempted from visa for their travels up to 90 days.
>   Ordinary passport holders are required to have visa to enter Turkey. Ordinary passport holders may obtain their 30-day single-entry e-Visas via www.evisa.gov.tr, provided that they have a valid Schengen or USA, UK, Ireland visa or residence permit and that they travel to Turkey with Turkish Airlines or Egypt Air.
>
> Besides, those ordinary passport holders who are under 20 or over 45 years old may get their 30-day single-entry e-Visas via the website www.evisa.gov.tr.

Somewhat similar requirements are shown on [Timatic on Emirates.com](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx), which also says that people eligible for e-Visas can acquire the e-Visa upon arrival at the airport.  The [Timatic on IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/TR-Turkey-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) information is slightly different, with no mention of age limits.

Given the varying information from different sites, it looks like the best plan is to use [www.evisa.gov.tr](http://www.evisa.gov.tr) ahead of time. If it works, you're all set; if not, you'll have to apply for a visa from the Turkish embassy.